# Summing up all permutations of row values

Tags: arrays, algorithm, matlab, matrix

I have a problem in MATLAB, and I think this could nicely be solved using e.g. recursion. I just wonder whether there is a more elegant (maybe vectorized) solution making use of some built-in functions.

So here is the problem:

Given is a (n x 2)-matrix. Find all possible summations where there is exactly one value per row in the sum.

Example 1:

```
A = [a b; 
     c d]; % I use variable names/symbolic values to make it clearar
```

Results 2:

```
result = [a+c; a+d; b+c; b+d];
```

Example 2:

```
A = [a b;
     c d;
     e f];

result = [a+c+e; a+c+f; a+d+e; a+d+f; b+c+e; b+c+f; b+d+e; b+d+f];
```

I hope my problem is clear :)
Thanks

Comment: Use this function to create all combinations http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10064-allcomb

Answer (score 2):

```
[m n] = size(A);
cols = dec2base(0:n^m-1,n)+1 - '0'; %// all combinations of cols
ind = bsxfun(@plus, 1:m, (cols-1)*m).'; %'// convert into linear index
result = sum(A(ind));
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, recursion is a good way.

Every such set of sums of an n-row matrix can be found by first calculating the set of sums of its first n-1 rows, and then adding either the bottom-left or the bottom-right number to each number in this set.  In pseudocode:

```
sumset(M):
    If nrows(M) = 1 then return { M[1, 1], M[1, 2] }.
    S = sumset(first nrows(M)-1 rows of M)
    X = { }
    For each number s in S:
        Insert M[nrows(M), 1] + s into X.
        Insert M[nrows(M), 2] + s into X.
    Return X.
```

This will produce 2^n numbers overall.